# Where are MAC OSX HTTP Live Streaming Tools

Tags: ios, macos, http-live-streaming

I am trying to install `mediastreamvalidator`, `mediastreamsegmenter`, `mediafilesegmenter tools` for my mac machine version 10.6.8.

As mentioned in below link about downloading required tools for development of Apple specified Http Live Server.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

As above article says:

> The tools are frequently updated, so you should download the current
>   version of the HTTP Live Streaming Tools from the Apple Developer
>   website. You can access them if you are a member of the iPhone
>   Developer Program. One way to navigate to the tools is to log onto
>   connect.apple.com, then click iPhone under the Downloads heading.

After logging in to site connect.apple.com with Mac OSX developer credentials,
under download heading there is no tab named iPhone, i am unable to find this link.

If these tools are stored else where can some one please provide me the updated link? 
I need these command lines for developing HLS server.

As I read on Apple web site, Mac OSX version 10.6 and above have these applications pr-installed and we don't need to install them using dgm files, but on my max machine i have only mediastreamsegmenter command line tools not all of them.

Can some one please provide me a link to download these command line tools or provide information on how to get these applications installed on my mac.

Comment: Are you a member of the iPhone Developer Program?

Comment: hi, no I am not a member of iPhone developer program but i have just registered myself as MAX OSX developer and i have tried to download these tools using MAC OSX developer login. Do I need to be register as iPhone developer for downloading these tools?

Comment: As it says in your quote: "You can access them *if you are a member of the iPhone Developer Program*"

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned by Stuart, you must be a member of the iPhone Developer Program in order to access these tools via the http://connect.apple.com link provided in the official documentation. More specifically, you must be a **paid member**. This fact caused me to lose several hours searching for the tools as I was a member of the iPhone Developer Program, but my annual membership had lapsed and the tools were consequently no longer available *to me*. What really got me was that the tools were still unavailable within the first few hours of renewing my membership. **It took approximately 12 - 24 hours after I paid to renew my membership for them to show up in the list**. Hope this helps someone down the road!

Answer (score 9):

They seem to be well-hidden for whatever reason, but after a few wild goose chases, I found them.

You can start at the public-facing streaming page: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

There is a "Downloads" link along the side.  You'll be prompted to sign in to your Developer account, and then finally you get the actual download page here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=http%20live%20streaming%20tools

Comment: Wow, glad I didn't pay apple and wait 24h like the top answer says.

Comment: It should be marked as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a copy make from lastest version of HTTP Live Streaming Tools on ADC.

https://github.com/creeveliu/HTTPLiveStreamingTools

Download:

`$ git clone https://github.com/creeveliu/HTTPLiveStreamingTools`

To install it, you just need to double-click the StreamingTools.pkg and follow the instructions.

Once installed you will have these tools

`/usr/local/bin/mediastreamsegmenter
    /usr/local/bin/mediafilesegmenter
    /usr/local/bin/mediasubtitlesegmenter
    /usr/local/bin/variantplaylistcreator
    /usr/local/bin/mediastreamvalidator
    /usr/local/bin/hlsreport.py
    /usr/local/bin/id3taggenerator`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10352971)

Comment: Basic installation info added