# Where can I get the "mediasegmenter" tool?

Tags: audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm studying HTTP Live streaming and I think I need .ts and the segment tool "mediasegmenter" but I can't find this tool on developer.apple.com

The only tool I could get was MakeRefMovie.

I've already searched https://developer.apple.com/streaming/.

Is MakeRefMovie the tool what I'm looking for? Then How can I seperate media file to chunk?

Comment: OK, Now I figured out why I couldn't the tool. My developer enrollment is pending. =)
I guess I will be able to download the tool after I pay for the enrollment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are MAC OSX HTTP Live Streaming Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106790/where-are-mac-osx-http-live-streaming-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer freedom, you can use this: https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor

It serves the same purpose as Apple's mediasegmenter, but is free and cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/about_apple_s_http_live_streaming_tools along with the description of the tools:

1. You go to https://developer.apple.com/streaming/
2. You follow the download link to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=HLS.

[image]