# Where do I get mediastreamsegmenter for http live streaming?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

I can't seem to find the mediastreamsegmenter or mediafilesegmenter command line utility for OSX Lion.  I have Xcode 4.5 installed and it's not in /usr/bin

Lots of google search results say to go to connect.apple.com and search for "http live streaming" but that only yields this:

[image]

[Developer tools link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=http%20) on right hand of [Apple's Http live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) site yields the same result.  Is this a replacement for these command line utilities?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

Did you try following these instructions? I don't have access myself, so I can't check

Comment: @vipw that's the problem, the docs on their site are incorrect.  I've reported this to Apple.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have two Apple IDs registered as iOS developers and neither can see these tools.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106790/where-are-mac-osx-http-live-streaming-tools - I think this answers my question - both my subscriptions lapsed a month ago!

Comment: I am a paid member and have been.  Today when I logged into the developer site it made me accept a new licensing agreement.  Didn't see that previously.  Now I can see the HTTP live streaming tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My developer subscription had lapsed.  Once renewed I could see the tool.

Comment: its free tool, so no subscription required

Answer (score 4):

Three important thing to follow to see this download available on the page.

1. You have to be a paid  iOS Developer Program Member
2. https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=http%20live%20streaming%20tools
3. You must use Safari Browser